# Encrypting with CryptoJS, decrypt with Ruby / AES

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption, cryptojs

This problem almost has me to my knees!

I'm trying do encrypt data that's going to be sent to a RoR-application via AJAX.

I've managed to encrypt a string in Ruby and decrypt it in JavaScript, but now I can't manage to do the reverse.

Here's my JS:

```
function decrypt(data, key) {
    var index = data.indexOf('!$');
    var iv = data.substr(0, index);
    var crypttext = data.substr(index + 2);

    encrypted = {}
    encrypted.ciphertext = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(crypttext);

    var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key, { iv: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(iv) });

    return decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
}

function encrypt( data, key ) {
    enc = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt( data, key );

    enc_str = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(enc.iv) + "!$" + CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(enc.ciphertext);

    return enc_str;
}
// ...
var key = 'ABCDEF123ABCDEF123ABCDEF123ABCDEF123ABCDEF123';//CryptoJS.SHA256( 'ABCDEF123' ).toString();
var key2 = 'ABCDEF123ABCDEF123ABCDEF123ABCDEF123ABCDEF123_42'; //CryptoJS.SHA256( 'ABCDEF123_42' ).toString();
code = "123 456"
    uuid = "0000000000000000000000000000"

var enc_code    = encrypt( code, key );
var enc_uuid    = encrypt( uuid, key2 );
```

I divided the iv and ciphertext because I had some problems with the Decryption in JS.

Here's the ruby code

```
def decrypt(string, key)
  salt = nil
  if string.include? '$$:'
    sp = string.split '$$:'
    string = sp[0]
    salt   = sp[1].to_i(16).to_s
  end

  parts = string.split '!$'

  @initialization_vector = Base64.decode64(parts[0])

  aes_decrypt(key, Base64.decode64(parts[1]), salt)
end

def aes(key,string)
  cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("aes-256-cbc")
  cipher.encrypt
  cipher.key = key #Digest::SHA256.digest(key)
  cipher.iv = @initialization_vector = cipher.random_iv# + '#'
  cipher_text = cipher.update(string)
  cipher_text << cipher.final
  return  cipher_text
end

def aes_decrypt(key, encrypted, salt = nil)
  p encrypted
  cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("aes-256-cbc")
  cipher.decrypt
  cipher.padding = 0 # I Spent a couple of hours with an exception from Cipher, all I had to do was add this line!!
  cipher.key = key #Digest::SHA256.digest(key)
  cipher.iv = encrypted.slice!(0, 16)
  unless salt.nil?
 #   cipher.pkcs5_keyivgen key, salt
  end
  d = cipher.update(encrypted)
  d << cipher.final
end
```

As you can see I tried to figure out a way to include the salt, but with no luck (Cipher wont accept the salt and asking for an octet)!

The decryption in Ruby just spits out gibbrish.
(The methods work, I've decrypted the string sent to the clientside (which decrypts w/o problems in JS) direct in Ruby, and that works fine!

Here's the weird thing, I tried to decrypt the string in JS right away, but that doesn't work either!
Here's the results:

```
CryptoJS.AES.decrypt( enc, key, { iv: enc.iv, salt: enc.salt } ).toString() // In encrypt()
// => 31323320343536
// => 30303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030

decrypt( enc_code, key ).toString(); // After encrypt
// => [EMPTY]
```

My Google-fu is failing me, I've tried most things I've found!

Any ideas??

Comment: Why do you use a salt in the first place?

Comment: @owlstead It's on by default (that how it seems anyway!).
The object you get from AES.encrypt contains a salt value ( see: https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#The_Cipher_Output ), and I guess that's the salt it uses (Why else would it be there?).
And I can't find how to turn it off!

Answer (score -1):

The libraries you are using are using the higher layers of OpenSSL. The higher layers support password based encryption. By default, your CryptoJS code seems to use the proprietary Password Based Key Derivation Function from OpenSSL. However, the Ruby code does less by default; it will simply use the key you've put in as a key, you need to do the key derivation yourself.

So if you want to use just a key (which should be random binary data, not text), you should use a [custom key and IV](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#Custom_Key_and_IV) in CryptoJS. On the other hand, if you want to use a password (and therefore salt value), you should be using [method-i-pkcs5_keyivgen](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Cipher.html#method-i-pkcs5_keyivgen). In that case you may also need to parse the OpenSSL encrypted BLOB.